# Development Site is Redirecting to Live Site, Even After Setting base-url

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, development, debugging, redirect

I have just set up a client live site to my development server and change the config live site URLs to my test server URL under `core_config_data` table i also have all the cache deleted but when i open my development server URL the site is keep going to live site i have tried opening the admin its going to live site too `.htaccess` has nothing in it for this redirection site using varnish cache.

Any one having any idea what i am missing.

Comment: Post your answer as an answer - not a comment. Then mark it as accepted.

Comment: @sonassi, posted but it is too simple to be truth, just to make sure we don't have a kiddish mistake here.

Comment: I do not think this is to localized - it's quite a common problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the three reasons I have seen a dev site redirect to production ...

- Be sure to clear and flush your cache
- Make sure your URLs are set in the admin for your development site
- We dump our production db, use sed to replace the production urls with dev urls, then import the dump to a dev db
- Make sure apache is listening for requests for your development urls

Comment: Add a fourth. Bad file/folder permissions cause Magento to write the cache files to system **/tmp** instead of var/tmp and var/cache.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have different databases for both installations. Also check that  `app/etc/local.xml` of each installation have correct (different, corresponding) credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Is it on the same server?! If so, check apache configuration for your test url. Also you can restart varnish, sometimes cache cleaning does not work.

Comment: Hey.. thanks for your answer!! Actually i resolved the issue i had took abackup of the local.xml and deleted it upload it again.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have to `flush magento cache`

and if you are not able to access your magento then follow my below trick

1) If you have `ssh` access

Create a shell Script with below code named `test.php` in root shell folder

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
require_once 'abstract.php';
class Mage_Shell_Test extends Mage_Shell_Abstract{
    public function run(){
        Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush();
       echo 'Done';
    }
  }
$shell = new Mage_Shell_Test();
$shell->run();
```

After creating this file login your SSH and go to your magento root and fire below command

```
php shell/test.php
```

2) If you dont have ssh access

Create a file in your magento root named `test.php`

with below code

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::init();
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush();
```

fire below URL in your browser `http://yourBaseUrl/test.php`